# How to act on paramters being passed to the homepage?

Tags: 7, uri

We have external sites direct users to our homepage. These external sites add information to the url which add additional information. This is an internal academic site so these parameters look like, for example, http://www.example.edu/?dept=classics
How can I get our homepage to detect and act on these parameters?

Comment: They're already available to PHP as `$_GET` variables – what kinds of things are you looking to do with this? Pass to Views? Pull in from a taxonomy vocabulary?

Comment: Well, yes, I know that they are accessible this way but from where? I am not sure where the entry point would be to use them. Should I try to hack index.php? Something else?

Comment: "How can I get our homepage to detect and act on these parameters?" - Can you be more specific as to how and what you want to do with those URL parameters?

Comment: No no no, do not hack index.php. If you want to provide a callback in PHP that presents content for the home page, do it in a module or a custom block. Or use the context module (drupal.org/project/context) to pass this information to Views or something. A custom module might sound like a plugin or something, but it actually represents the "correct" way to work with the Drupal API to build dynamic, custom websites.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. May you provide the information asked by @DavidThomas? Without knowing that, the question becomes too broad. Listing all the hooks that you could use is quite useless to you, and future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my approach would be to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in a `hook_preprocess_HOOK` (see [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7)) on `template.php` in a theme folder if all I needed to do is theming based on it.  For example:

```
function example_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $current_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  // and so on
}
```

And then you could `explode()` it, modify stuff in the page array or the node array, etc.

Comment: It occurs to me now that you would probably want to sanitize as well.  See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/group/sanitization/7

Comment: And this is an alternative for getting the request_uri: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be in the `function example_preprocess_page(&$variables)` of your template.php file you can use the `drupal_is_front_page()` to determine if you are on the homepage. Then use `$somevariable = $_GET['q'];` to pull out the variable and act on that. Please note, this is untested.